# Strange Space Behavior in SpannableStringBuilder

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm working on an Android app, and I've encountered some unexpected behavior when using `SpannableStringBuilder` to format text. Specifically, I noticed a difference in spacing when adding a space character programmatically versus including it in the string resource itself. This is the code I ran into:

```kotlin
info.text = SpannableStringBuilder().append(
    getString(
        R.string.textWithColon,
        "Text before colon",
    )
)
.bold {
    append(" ") // Add space here
    append(
        getString(
            R.string.someOtherText,
            "More text here",
        )
    )
}
```

I wanted to remove `append(" ")`, and just add the space in resource string.

```xml
<string name="textWithColon" translatable="false">%1$s: </string>
```

Unfortunately, no matter how many spaces I add here, they will not be visible on the UI. Is there any way to achieve the space after colon, without adding it with `append()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add end of your string resource *\u0020* like this:

```
<string name="textWithColon" translatable="false">%1$s:\u0020</string>
```

Comment: Seems to be working pretty well, thanks. Do you know what the difference is technically?

Comment: In [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#FormattingAndStyling) says Android collapse these spaces and accept them as Unicode spaces. To preserve these spaces you should use quotes or Android escaping like in the answer.